# How to implement HTTP & SSL in the same port (3000)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin, webrick

I have a Rails app and I use Webrick as a development server.

I'm trying to test SSL locally but it's not practical for us to run 2 instances on different ports (3000 - 3001) in order to have SSL.

Is there a way to do this in one port?

thanks!

Comment: Unless you're proposing to tunnel HTTP over SSL this is not possible - the whole point about ports is to separate the protocols.

Comment: Run Apache or nginx on your dev box and use the ports 80 and 443, pointing to 3000 and 3001 respectively. Then your browser will handle it automatically.

Comment: Checking I think HTTP + SSL = HTTPS so what issue then

Answer (score 0):

You can't run them on the same port as they are completely separate protocols, that said there is a large movement towards making everything run on HTTPS, so if you have certificate, and don't mind encrypting everything, that might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Technically, you could run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port. [Grizzly can do that with *port unification* in Java](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2006/11/07/one-tcp-port-to-rule-them-all/). Whether this is really necessary in practice is another topic...